Draw a 3D plot of beams of an antenna using Pgfplots or any other package
Hi can someone help me with the 3D plot of the following 2D plot
The latex code for this is:
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % First beam (3D effect with fading color)
    \draw[thick, color=blue, line width=1.2pt] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] 
        ({180 + 10*sin(\t)}:{2*(sin(\t/2))^3});

    % Second beam (different color and perspective effect)
    \draw[thick, color=red, line width=1.5pt] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] 
        ({135 + 12*sin(\t)}:{6*(sin(\t/2))^3});

    % Central point with 3D shading
    \shade[ball color=black] (0,0) circle (0.1);
    \node[label=right:$x$] at (0,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

I want to achieve something like this:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The real key to making those sorts of 3D surface plots is knowing two things: (1) what coordinate system it is in, and (2) what is the surface's mathematical definition (typically as a parametric function). This reminds me of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/376028984_Visualizing_atomic_orbitals_of_an_electron_by_Latex which are done in spherical coordinates. Wave propagation and atomic orbitals are two different things though, so you may need cylindrical coordinates.

After further investigation here: https://5gstore.com/blog/2024/06/26/how-to-interpret-antenna-radiation-patterns/, I can say that your diagram is probably in spherical coordinates

I had this code lying around on my computer, so I thought I would post it. The formula is from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/376028984_Visualizing_atomic_orbitals_of_an_electron_by_Latex, but any polar formula would work.
tikz-3dplot is only capable of drawing the figures with the z-axis upright. So, you can't get the z-axis to point horizontally yet in spherical surface graphs- unless you program the software yourself (which I might do for you for fun, if time permits).
Note that this formula most certainly isn't the exact formula you are looking for. What I am showing you is spherical surface plot syntax.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
line join=bevel
,tdplot_main_coords
,fill opacity=1]
\begin{scope}[scale=5]
    \tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{90}{0}{360}
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(7)/(4*sqrt(pi))*(5*(cos(\tdplottheta))^3-3*cos(\tdplottheta))}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
    {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
    -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
    {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
    -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
    {\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
    -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


With the fill opacity at 0.5,


The solution I mentioned which would allow you to draw this in any orientation would be similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728413/319072

Thank you this is so useful

I'm not entirely sure what you're hoping to achieve with the 3D version of that plot. However, you can easily "convert" that plot into 3D using the package tikz-3dplot.
Here is a simple MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120} % Adjust the viewing angle as you wish.

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

    \shade[ball color=black] (0,0,0) circle (0.2);
    \node[label=right:$x$] at (0,0,0) {};

    \draw[thick, color=blue, line width=1pt, tdplot_screen_coords] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] 
        ({1.5*sin(\t)*cos(\t)}, {0.5*cos(\t)}, {0.5*sin(\t)});

    \draw[thick, color=red, line width=1.5pt, tdplot_screen_coords] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=51] 
        ({3*sin(\t)*cos(\t)}, {sin(\t)}, {2*cos(\t)});

    % Optional: Axis for perspective (may be good a addition to your work)
    \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,4) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The above code produces the following output:

I hope this is what you're looking for! If not, please provide more details so I can adjust the solution accordingly.
P.S. I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment; otherwise, I would have done so to clarify your question.
EDIT: This answer was given before the updated post in which OP did not state the final result that he wanted.
